# What is the exact power of prime $p$ dividing $k^{n}-1$, where $k$ is a positive integer and $p \nmid k-1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For a positive integer $n$ and prime number $p$,  $V_{p}(n)$ denotes the exact power of $p$ dividing $n$.

**Question:**  What is the value of $V_{p}(k^n-1),$ where $k$ is a positive integer, $p>2$ and $p \nmid k-1$ and $p\nmid k$?

Motivation:

By lifting the exponent lemma, we have that for an odd prime $p$, if  $p \mid k-1$ and $p \nmid k$, then $V_{p}(k^n-1)= V_{p}(k-1)+V_{p}(n)$. A natural question arise that what we can say about $V_{p}(k^n-1)$ when $p \nmid k-1$.
If $p-1 \mid n$, then by Fermat Little Theorem, $V_{p}(k^n-1)\geq 1 $ (but unable to compute the exact value).
Also I think that, if $p-1 \nmid n$, then $V_{p}(k^n-1)=0$.

Comment: $V_{p}(k^n-1)\geq 1$ holds only when $\gcd(p,k)=1$ along with $p-1\mid n$ as you mentioned.

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya Note with $\gcd(p, k) = 1$ that $V_p(k^n - 1) \ge 1$ can also be true even when $p - 1 \not\mid n$, e.g., $p = 7$, $k = 2$ and $n = 3$.

Comment: Yeah, but it's true when $k$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.

Comment: The question essentially concerns the complete factorization of $(k^n-1)/(k-1)$, and thus stands too broad IMO. Even the case $k=2$ is still far from being answered completely.